# Properly Setting Red Hat Daemon Umask

Tags: permissions, rhel, daemon, umask

I've been trying to figure out the proper location to set daemon umasks in RedHat 5. All my searches lead to setting it in `/etc/init.d/functions` or `/etc/sysconfig/init`.

What are the pros/cons of setting the `umask` in one place over another?  Is one location more secure than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set it in /etc/sysconfig/init because that gets sourced later on in the .etc/init.d/functions script than the explicit umask command does and as such it takes precedence.

Not to mention /etc/init.d/functions is a script file whereas /etc/sysconfig/init is a configuration file. Scripts may be updated by rpm but newer config files just get saved as configFileName.rpmnew. So if you change it in functions, an update may things cause things to start breaking and it will be non-intuitive to figure out why.